# Application for BlackBerry beginners

Tags: blackberry, mobile

Which kind of application would anyone suggest to start working on/developing for a novice [BlackBerry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry) who has hardly spent 4-5 days checking out the API's and the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write some simple application, you may port small open source game from [J2ME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Micro_Edition). You will not have to think about business logic and resources.

My first BlackBerry application was [plain puzzle](http://code.google.com/p/bbpuzzled).

There are several articles about writing fully functional applications:

[Creating a Blackberry Game by Toni Westbrook](http://www.toniwestbrook.com/archives/69)
[Thinking BlackBerry - GPS application](http://www.thinkingblackberry.com/archives/226)
[CodeProject - End-to-End Real World BlackBerry Application By MiamiCoder](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/EndToEndBlackBerryApp.aspx)

Also I recommend the complete [BlackBerry Java Development Environment Labs](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/resources/developer_labs.jsp#tab_tab_jde).

Answer (score 1):

[Hello world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_world_program) might be a nice start.
[My first BlackBerry Java Application](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/27869/0/page/3).

Comment: I did that already! I meant something which is of atleast some use

Comment: ah, hehe, in which case. Have you tried building something like a calculator?

Answer (score 1):

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Useful-links-for-novice-and-experienced-programmers/td-p/116924

Answer (score 0):

A Stack Overflow application! ;^)

Comment: That will something really good. But I hardly have any idea- how to go for it. What to do, how to do, where to start. Making the gui is alright but what about everything else